# Parameter value '421.0526000000' is out of range

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, decimal

I have a table called User which has a column called Efficiency . 
I've set the column type to decimal(30,15)
In visual studio i have calculated a decimal nr = 421.0525 and I can see in the dubbuger that nr doesn't change its value.
 I've set the Efficiency column of the table to be equal to my nr.
When I'm trying to save the changes

```
db.SaveChanges();`
```

I get the following error :

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
ArgumentException: Parameter value '421.0526000000' is out of range.
```

I've tried setting the column type to decimal(18,10), decimal(20,10),decimal(10,4) etc. The result is the same. ??
I'm using Visual studio 2017 and Sql Server 2017.
Thank you

Comment: Please show the structure of the table via its CREATE TABLE statement and the SQL statement of the update being executed.

Comment: The words "Parameter value" in the error message implies that perhaps a Stored Procedure is being called.  If this is the case, what are the parameters, and how is it being called?